# Sorting Versioned ModelAdmin

Tags: silverstripe, modeladmin

I'm trying to do a custom sort in ModelAdmin on SiteTree object

```
public function getList() {
    $list = parent::getList();

    if($this->modelClass == 'Listing') {
        $list = $list->sort(array('Status' => 'ASC','Street' => 'ASC'));
    }
    return $list;
}
```

The sort works but when you try to edit a record I get the following error:

```
[User Error] Couldn't run query: SELECT DISTINCT "SiteTree_Live"."ID", "Status", "Street" FROM "SiteTree_Live" WHERE ("SiteTree_Live"."ClassName" IN ('Listing','UnavailableListing')) ORDER BY "Status" ASC, "Street" ASC LIMIT 30 Unknown column 'Status' in 'field list'
```

Obviously Status doesn't exist on SiteTree, it exists on Listing.

Answer (score 1):

You've kind of answered your own question. You can't order by `Status` when querying `SiteTree` if the column doesn't exist on that table.

You need to change your model class to `Listing` or add the `Status` column to your `SiteTree` table.

Comment: I'm using `public static $managed_models = array(
  'Listing' => array("title" => 'Listings'),
  'MLSListing' => array("title" => 'MLS Listings'),
  'UnavailableListing' => array("title" => 'Unavailble Listings')
 );`